# How do I test that items are sorted alphabetically in drop down menu using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Suppose, there is a country drop-down on a web page where the world's 195 countries listed in alphabetic order, I have to validate whether they are arranged alphabetically or not. How do I do that?
I can store them in an ArrayList object by adding all the countries one by one, but it's a huge work. Is there any smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First we need to store all the available dropdown options in an ArrayList.

 Then create a temporary list and to sort them in ascending order use Collections.sort method. 
Finally match the temporary list with the dropdown list using equals() method.

Please refer the code below which is built on [this](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html) site,

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-select-dropdown-demo.html");

    // Locating select tag web element
    WebElement singleSelectTagDropdownWebElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select-demo\"]"));
    Select dropdown = new Select(singleSelectTagDropdownWebElement);

    // Get all options
    List<WebElement> allOptionsElement = dropdown.getOptions();

    // Creating a list to store drop down options
    List options = new ArrayList();


    for(WebElement optionElement : allOptionsElement)
    {
        options.add(optionElement.getText());
    }

    // Removing "Please select" option as it is not actual option
    options.remove("Please select");

    System.out.println("Options in dropdown with Default order :"+options);

    // Creating a temp list to sort
    List tempList = new ArrayList(options);

    Collections.sort(tempList);

    System.out.println("Sorted List "+ tempList);

    boolean ifSortedAscending = options.equals(tempList);

    if(ifSortedAscending)
    {
        System.out.println("List is sorted");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("List is not sorted.");

    driver.quit();
```

Please go [here](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/11/25/how-to-verify-if-options-in-dropdown-are-sorted-as-expected-in-selenium-webdriver-java/) for more details.